# trying to count all votes from voting table but I get an error on line 153

Tags: php

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/students/gar0349/public_html/project2voting.php on line 153

```
<?php
$totalvotes = ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM voting WHERE votes >= 0 ");
    $totalvotesresults = mysql_query( $totalvotes )
or die( "Could not get total votes " .mysql_error() );
$data = mysql_fetch_object( $totalvotesresults );
echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data['total'] ."</div>\n";;
?>
```

Comment: Which one of these lines is 153?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = mysql_fetch_object( $totalvotesresults );
```

you are fetching as object so you need to use as

```
$data->total;


echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data->total ."</div>\n";;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is an object, not an array.
Try:

```
echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data->total ."</div>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$totalvotes = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM voting WHERE votes >= 0 ";
    $totalvotesresults = mysql_query( $totalvotes )
or die( "Could not get total votes " .mysql_error() );
$data = mysql_fetch_object( $totalvotesresults );
echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data->total ."</div>\n";
?>
```

Remove The First Bracket From First Line QUery .. And aslo

```
    echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data->total ."</div>\n";
```

Comment: i have 8 votes in my table but in my output it says i have 5 votes in total

Comment: First Of All Check Your Where Condition .. And Second You can give me your table information So that i can suggest ..